# RPi 3 B+ won't start after accidentally connected 3.3v gpio pin to 5v gpio pin

Tags: gpio

I guess everything is in the title. I wasn't trying to connect any pins. It sounds stupid but I was holding my keys and was just trying to put the usb power supply on the Pi and accidentally connected 3.3v and 5v or both 5v (don't really know). Now only the red LED is on. Is my Pi dead?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49415/accidentally-connected-3-3v-gpio-pin-to-5v-gpio-pin

This asks whether you saw any smoke.

Comment: I didn't see any smoke coming out

Comment: @kwasmich yes it is. I just killed my Pi lol. Thanks for the help

Comment: Try possibly making a new SD card, then put it in... it is very unlikely though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others it seems like you may have shorted your device. I would suggest following some troubleshooting such as [here](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting) to potentially resolve your issue if that is not the case. There is a section titled "Red power LED is on, green LED does not flash, nothing on display".

However you most likely need a new device or need it to be repaired if you shorted your device.

Answer (score 0):

The expression of "letting the smoke out"  is just that, silly expression ,  and is based on believe that each device is filled with smoke during manufacturing.

An unprotected  device, such as protection against incorrect DC polarity with "an idiot diode ",  will fail in nanosecond.

"Troubleshooting"  hardware such as yours after the mishap is waste of your time and resources.

Get a new one and learn from this experience is the best you can do.